# Reducing whitespace from document

Tags: formatting, pdftex

I am writing a paper in tex (see screenshot) and I am observing that the renderer sometimes leaves a lot of space between two sections. 
Especially, if I have a table at the end of the section then there is a lot whitespace between the table and the beginning of the next section.

Is there a documentwide setting that I can use to reduce this wasted whitespace?

**UPDATE** Here's a link to a full overleaf project. https://www.overleaf.com/8871433zwvgwsnqtrhj

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CODE FOR IMAGE 1 RIGHT COLUMN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
The above proposition shows that if $\ab=\bb$ and $\cb \ge 0$ then by setting
$\bE = \rp \cap B(\ab, ||\ab||)$ we can satisfy the above constraints.
Unfortunately, we were not able to drive suitable constraints for models C and
D. \tabref{tab:proptrans} summarizes our proposed constraints.
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.2pt}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c | l}
    Model & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Constraints}\\\hline
    A & $\begin{aligned}
      &\r_1'' \ge \lambda \r_1, \lambda \r_2 + (1-\lambda)\r'_1 \le \Z\\
      & \ip{\e''}{\r_2''} \ge (1-\lambda)\ip{\e'}{\r_2'}\end{aligned}$\\[1ex]\hline
    B & $\begin{aligned}
      &\r_1'' + \e'' + (1-\lambda)(\r_1' + \e')=0,\\
      &{\ip{\r_2''}{\e''} \ge (1-\lambda)\ip{\r_2'}{\e'}}, \text{and}\\
      &\ab \ge \Z, \forall x \in \cE,\ \x \in \rp \cap B(\ab, ||\ab||)\end{aligned}$\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sufficient constraints for enforcing $\proptrans(r, r', e', r'',
    e'')$. $\ab = \frac{\r_1'' - \lambda \r_1 + \e''}{\lambda}$.}
  \label{tab:proptrans}
\end{table}



\subsubsection{Type Implication}
```

[image: example]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CODE FOR IMAGE 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tabref{tab:impl} summarizes the constraints for
different scoring functions.
\begin{table}[htbp]
  %\centering
  \begin{tabular}{r | l}
    Model & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Constraints}\\\hline
    A, \AR , B &  $\r \le \r'$\\
    C, D &  $\r \le \r' \le -\r$
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{Constraints sufficient for enforcing $\implication(r, r')$ under different
  score models and composition functions. The constraint that $\e \ge \Z \forall
  e \in \cE$ applies in all rows.}
  \label{tab:impl}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Reverse Relational Implication}
```

[image: Example 2]

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CODE FOR PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2017}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=2pt]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes} % insert [disable] to disable all notes.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathtools,graphicx,url,xspace,booktabs,microtype}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[]{breqn}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
% ------------- listings -------------- %
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[]{changepage}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,linewidth=10cm}
% ------------- algorithmicx --------------- %
% The package algorithmicx itself doesn’t define any algorithmic commands
% algpseudocode is the predefined command set that must be used.
\usepackage{algorithm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\LeftComment}[1]{\(\triangleright\) #1}%
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{0.6em}%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter%
\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}{\ALG@tlm\z@}{\leftmargin\z@\ALG@tlm\z@}{}{}%
\makeatother
% Set skips to very low values
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
```

Comment: the usual mechanism to avoid those spaces is to put the tables in a `table` environment that allows latex to move them to get better page breaks, but hard to say as you have shown no code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your time and the comment. I have added code from the preamble and snippets corresponding to the images.

Comment: Could you please post a complete MWE so that others can play around with it?

Comment: It looks as though perhaps (not sure) `caption`'s `auto` feature isn't detecting the caption placement correctly, so it is putting the skip below the caption rather than above. Try specifying the location explicitly. Otherwise, post a complete MWE demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I have no idea what `acl2017.sty` says. So you might see if that says anything relevant.

Comment: @JPi Hi, I uploaded my project to overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/8871433zwvgwsnqtrhj
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suggest you remove all code that is not causing your problem, instead of posting the whole file for us to examine, for which less people will have the patience and time. You might find the problem yourself while writing the MWE.